# WooCommerce How to setup variable product?

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am using WC 2.0.18. PHP 5.3, Apache 2.2, Mysql 5.5

Here is my question:

I create a product and set it to "variable product". A "selec" attribute called "date" is added and the following value is entered:

28/10/2013 | 29/10/2013 | 30/10/2013 | 31/10/2013

So I should expect that there are 4 values in the drop down box, I suppose.

Now, I went to "variation" and add all 4 variations, and select the date I want to set and enter qty, price and SKU. After everything is set, I save and go back to front-end, the drop down list does not show any variation that I am entering.

What's wrong? Can anyone please help me on this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the solution to myself for late comer reference.

Using 28/10/2013 will not work, but if I use 28 Oct 2013, it works.

So try to avoid using special character like '/'.  It will be fine...